Could linux give clearer error messages to distinguish files from directories?
mkdir temp
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘temp’: File exists
rm temp/
rm: cannot remove 'temp/': Is a directory

Is there any reason why the first error message should not be "Directory exists"?  I get that everything is a file in some sense but it's not helpful if rm then refuses to delete because it is not a file.
Also, "Is a directory" is really not a sentence. Could it be "It is a directory." instead?

Technically, a directory is a specific type of a file, and the error from mkdir  would be the same even if temp was a regular file, so that makes sense.  However, rm is to remove non-directory files (unless you use rm -r), so I don't really see the issue there. To remove directories, you'd use rmdir, and if you try to use that on a non-directory you get the error "Not a directory", which also makes sense.

In mkdir’s case, the underlying mkdir function doesn’t distinguish files from directories; it returns an error, EEXIST, corresponding to “File exists”.
In rm’s case, the removal fails with an EISDIR error, corresponding to “Is a directory”.
The mkdir behaviour and the text descriptions of the errors are specified by POSIX, they’re not specific to Linux. rm’s specification doesn’t require the use of the EISDIR error, but that’s what the implementation you’re using does. I’m not sure whether POSIX requires that the diagnostic messages produced by utilities such as mkdir and rm match the text description given in the specification exactly, but that’s what the implementers of the utilities you’re using chose to do (at least in English; POSIX doesn’t specify translations, they are provided by the C library in this instance).
So the messages could be clearer, at the expense of more work (in the mkdir scenario, with an additional race condition to handle), and probably some effort determining whether deviating from the “safe” POSIX messages is acceptable.
